# name error on serial comm with pi to arduino

Tags: python, serial-port

Hi i have the following code and keep getting this error message:

NameError: name 'serial' is not defined

I have copied this code off numerous tutorials and it just won't work can somebody tell me why?

```
from serial import*
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:
    ser.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import in this way:

```
from serial import *
```

you are importing things as if they were declared inside the actual file. From Python Docs:

> This imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (`_`). Note that in general the practice of `importing * from` a module or package is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code. However, it is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions.

So you can call `Serial` like:

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

---

If you don't want to import it this way (you may have problems overwriting fields or already used identifiers) you can use:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

Comment: ive tried what you said but still get error saying Serial is not defined? i have noticed it doesnt change colour either,so i my current code is this:

import serial

ser= Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:
    ser.readline()

Comment: I think you misunderstood, one way is `from serial import *` and `ser = Serial(...)`. Another way is `import serial` and `ser = serial.Serial(...)`

Comment: tried both of those and i still get an error, is there a simple way to check i have serial installed correctly?

Comment: You could try this in an empty file: `import serial` and in the next line `print serial`. If you get an exception that tells that module doesn't exist, it is not correctly installed.

Comment: just tried that and this is the error i get......

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/IEP/test/tttt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/IEP/test/serial.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser= Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
NameError: name 'Serial' is not defined

Comment: You are importing it as `import serial` and calling it with `ser = Serial(...)`. That's **not** what I said, if you use that kind of import, call it as `serial.Serial(...)`

Comment: i have also just typed.....sudo apt-get install python-serial and it is telling me it is already installed and the newest version?

Comment: sorry just to clarify that error was from the blank file and just typing import serial print serial

Comment: That most recent error is because you have a file named serial.py in the same directory as tttt.py, and it's importing that instead of the  "serial" module you want.  Temporarily rename serial.py to something else, then continue with the suggested test of tttt.py

Comment: Thanks! thats worked perfectly (I'm now going to hang my head in shame)

Answer (score 0):

Your first line needs to be:

```
from serial import *
```

You need a space between the `import` and the `*`.

Secondly, when you import in this fashion, you don't need to prepend `serial`. It should be:

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have pySerial installed. If you don't, try

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial
```